# Missing 'libaudiopolicyservice_intermediates" when trying to compile AOSP 7.1.1 release 6?

Tags: android, build, compilation, android-source, ninja

```
ninja: error: 'out/target/product/victara/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libaudiopolicymanager_intermediates/export_includes', needed by 'out/target/product/victara/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libaudiopolicyservice_intermediates/import_includes', missing and no known rule to make it
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (04:02 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I got this error when compiling AOSP for victara (Moto X 2nd generation)... Anyone know how to fix ?

I'm using this local manifest: https://github.com/renanmarcs/local_manifests/blob/master/local.xml

And this is how I started to compile:

```
cd ~/aosp
repo sync
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_victara-userdebug
make -j2
```

Comment: At first try a clean build if you have not tried yet. "make clean" followed by "make clobber" then ". build/envsetup.sh" and the rest

Comment: @GodslaveAsad I've tried this but no succeed. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: I've changed "USE_CUSTOM_AUDIO_POLICY" in "BoardConfig.mk" to "0" for disable this option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the common folder within qcom folder ?

If no then get the `device/qcom/common` folder from cm.

Add this line to your `local_manifest.xml`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've added 'device/qcom/common' and 'hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8974' and 'hardware/qcom/display-caf/msm8974' and 'hardware/qcom/audio-caf/msm8974' and 'device/qcom/sepolicy' from CyanogenMod... So I've entered 'make clean' and 'make clobber' then tried to build... Same error.